# How to add button to specific place of existed panel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm newbie with UI in java.

Have a problem with adding button to existed panel:

```
public void run() {
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 756));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() / 2) - 600);
    int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() / 2) - 378);
    frame.setLocation(x, y);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    createScene();
    panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //start_button
    start_button.setBounds(200, 550, 230, 69);
    panel.add(start_button);

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    File a = new File("src/images/connection_error.png");
    File parentFolder = new File(a.getParent());
    File b = new File(parentFolder, "../images/connection_error.png");

    try {
        loadURL("file:/" + b.getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleSwingBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    startLoader("ftp://31.130.206.175/client_content/index.html");

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This *start_button* just overlay the whole panel, but I need it just to be placed in specific location with specific size. It should not mess any items on the panel (there image and loaded http). What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: `I need it just to be placed in specific location with specific size.` - you should not be coding like that. You should be using layout managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must skip using `BorderLayout` for your `panel` - that is causing the button to fill whole container - and set `jfxPanel`s bounds manualy just like you are doing it with the button before adding it to `panel.

More on layout managers and in general - `Swing` component placement can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html